# How to design a database model for User Editable Fields?

Tags: database-design

I am trying to design a database model where the users could edit fields freely and I would be able to verify the changes and merge them. A similar user-managed model is used here on stack overflow where others can edit answers and improve them. The edits are not automatically applied, only after approval.

This is the model that I am working with, a switch object or array with multiple UUID objects in it:

```
{
  "switches": {
    "UUID": {
      "created": "date",
      "force": {
        "operating": "55g",
        "peak": "95g"
      },
      "rating": {
        "current": "10mA",
        "maximum": "12V maximum AC/DC"
      },
      "type": "tactile",
      "lifespan": "50 million"
    }
  }
}
```

This comes with its own challenges:

How would I keep this simple to manage?
I need a clear way of knowing what properties were changed and what was not.
I would need to be able to merge objects but only the properties that got changed. In a way, like git keeps track of history I would need to keep track of the object's previous edits.

One approach would be:

1. On each edit would create a copy of the original object and just reference in the original object the edited objects UUID.
2. Then in the control panels code compare the two objects and compare their creation date and edit dates and merge the properties that got changed from the edited object.

But this wouldn't work because

1. Multiple edits of properties where multiple people change the fields would make hard to merge.
2. It would become messy over time as I would have the edited objects and the original objects in the same place and sorting them would take more and more time.
3. This would not allow me to track changes over time as everything would just get merged into the original object.

Is there a better way to do this with references? Like each field would have a reference to an edited object's edited property?

I am new to database design and my project right now has no database setup, so I have the option to go either sql or nosql.

Comment: Do all switches have the same data attributes (UUID, created, force, rating etc.)?

Comment: Yes the keys are the same only the values differ

Comment: In the case of a merge conflict, who wins?

Comment: This seems a bit broad and likely more than just a DB feature. What kind of DB (relational, document, etc)?

Comment: Yes this is more of an open question as I have the freedom to use any tools that are suitable.

Comment: > I will create a history table, every time main table only save the
> latest record, previous records go to history table by table trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your answer I would do following things:
You starre all Users as Json File.

Save the changes (included the value before) as seperate Json and than apply the changes it on the original.
Than there is an SQLite database or something like this which knowes all the JSON-Filenames.

To notice the changes you only take the Before JSON and After and compare all Values if they are equal.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

This is often called a [temporal database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database); your database engine may have built-in support. Googling temporal database will also bring up solutions designed specifically for your use case.

There are a few ways to model this. My preference is to use "valid_from/valid_until" fields.

So, your table structure might be something like:

```
Switch:
-------------
UUID (pk)
valid_from (pk)
valid_until
approved_flag
Created
operating_force
operating_peak_force
rating_current
rating_maximum
type
lifespan
```

When the user creates the record, `valid_from` is the creation date; `valid_until` is null. When you get a new version of the record, you set the `valid_until` to the modification date, and create a new row with `valid_from` as the modification date and `valid_until` is null.

This allows you to see what the state of the record was at any point in time; by comparing current with current-1, you can see what the delta is.

The challenge is dealing with "who wins if two people modify a record at the same time". By creating a composite primary key on UUID and valid_from, in the very unlikely circumstances that two people make a change at exactly the same time, one of those would be rejected. However, it's possible that the record changes between the time the user loads their screen, modifies the data, and tries to save it.

To handle that case, you can include application logic to compare the `valid_from` value at the time of loading with that same field when you try to modify it; if they are different, the UI can alert the user.

Comment: The challenge of "who wins if two people modify a record at the same time" becomes more complicated as I would want to manually approve each change. Because of this there is a fairly high chance that two changes will happen on the same object but for different keys. The question becomes: How would I save the field changes in the DB to prevent/reduce merge conflicts? I should not save the whole object preferably. I think I should save only the changed key/value pair in a separate collection.
This way I could have 1 user change `operating_force`, and another one change `operating_peak_force`.

Comment: Before I update the question - would the person updating "operating_peak_force" care about the value of "operating_force" when making their change?

Comment: No they would not. Also, the feature that would allow to view the history of edits is more of a nice to have, but not a necessity. But the merging and clean database structure is a must-have, so I could scale the application without fearing that the data will become unreadable to admins. Also does it matter in this case if I use a noSQL or SQL database?

Comment: Is it possible for a record to have pending changes, and for different users to want to override those pending changes? E.g. user A sets operating_peak_force to 12, and while the record is awaiting approval, user B set it to 200?

Comment: No its not important for my use case

Answer (score 0):

I will create a history table, every time main table only save the latest record(no matter which field is changed), previous records go to history table by table trigger.

Then later you can use diff function to find who change what .